# Is it possible that the Google Script App Web App can fill a TextBox of my web page?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm  confused with the integration of Google Script App embedded with Web App in an iFrame on my webpage to interacts with the HTML of it. I think that it is not possible to do it, but I need to ask. Google Script works perfectly, but my question is: *Is it possible to make Google Web App fill a TextBox of my web page with some text?* Simply that when click on a button in the Google Script run a function that can fill a text box on my website with something.

I only want to execute this but instead of "TEXT" a value of a variable from the Google Script. Thank you.

```js
function myJsFunc() {
  document.getElementsByClassName('field-element text')[0]
    .setAttribute("value", "TEXT");
}
```

Comment: You can get the data from a spreadsheet with an httpRequest and then populate the texttbox yourself.

Comment: @Cooper thanks for answer but the way my Script works is with google drive and it is used with an "Add to cart" form on a e-commerce website to get data on the Cart Invoice when a user make a purchase, need to be complete auto to get the name of the file and this is just only the thing I need to complete

Comment: I'm not sure what means but I think it means you don't know how to use Javascript to access a server.  Or don't want too.

Comment: Yes, I don't know how to use javascript to access a server, and the website it isn't mine and is on Squarespace platform, that make all more complex. If you think that with an httpRequest from a spreadsheet I can do this, I will start with it. Thank you and sorry

Comment: You can do it with an httpRequest but I didn't say it was going to be easy if it's the first time you've ever done it.

Comment: Okey, I will start with it. It is not a problem if it is not ease. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Call the Parents

You can normally use the `window.parent` from the iframe to access the containing web page `document`

```js
function myFunc() {
window.parent.document.getElementsByClassName('field-element text')[0]
    .setAttribute("value", "TEXT");
}
```

I can't test this on Square Space but usually content of the iframe and the webpage need to have the same origin, so if I had to guess, I would say it won't work with Apps Script.

Alternatively, it looks like Square Space does support [custom JS](https://developers.squarespace.com/custom-javascript).

You could use the [**Apps Script API**](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/how-tos/execute#javascript) to make a request to run a function from JavaScript.

That said, if you are just trying to `.setAttribute` or even something more complex, if you use the Apps Script API then you can just cut out the Apps Script step entirely. Or you use your web app as an API itself with `doGet` and `doPost` function with parameters.

#### References

- [custom JS on squarespace](https://developers.squarespace.com/custom-javascript)
- [Apps Script API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/how-tos/execute#javascript)

Comment: Thank for your answer but with google script app this not works. After a lot of research this user explain the only way to archive this: [link](https://joshuatz.com/posts/2019/google-apps-script-authorization-in-a-cross-origin-iframe/)